# Grok - parsing optional fields

Tags: regex, logstash, field, logstash-grok

I've got data coming from kafka and I want to send them to ElasticSearch.  I've got a log like this with tags:

```
<TOTO><ID_APPLICATION>APPLI_A|PRF|ENV_1|00</ID_APPLICATION><TN>3</TN></TOTO>
```

I'm trying to parse it with `grok` using grok debugger:

```
\<ID_APPLICATION\>%{WORD:APPLICATION}\|%{WORD:PROFIL}\|%{WORD:ENV}\|%{WORD:CODE}\</ID_APPLICATION\>\<TN\>%{NUMBER:TN}\</TN\>
```

It works, but sometimes the log has a new field like this (the one with the tag `<TP>`):

```
<TOTO><ID_APPLICATION>APPLI_A|PRF|ENV_1|00</ID_APPLICATION><TN>3</TN><TP>new</TP></TOTO>
```

I'd like to get lines with this field (the TP tag) and lines without. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using : http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ as a debugger ?

Comment: It looks like you can use an optional group: `<ID_APPLICATION>%{WORD:APPLICATION}\|%{WORD:PROFIL}\|%{WORD:ENV}\|%{WORD:CODE}</ID_APPLICATION><TN>%{NUMBER:TN}</TN>(?:<TP>%{WORD:TP}</TP>)?`. Please try and let me know if this is working for you.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Please consider accepting [my below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34748503/3832970).

Answer (score 12):

If you have an optional field, you can match it with an optional named capturing group:

```
(?:<TP>%{WORD:TP}</TP>)?
^^^                    ^
```

The non-capturing group does not save any submatches in memory and is used for grouping only, and `?` quantifier matches 1 or 0 times (=optional). It will create a `TP` field with a value of type word. If the field is absent, the value will be `null`.

So, the whole pattern will look like:

```
<ID_APPLICATION>%{WORD:APPLICATION}\|%{WORD:PROFIL}\|%{WORD:ENV}\|%{WORD:CODE}</ID_APPLICATION><TN>%{NUMBER:TN}</TN>(?:<TP>%{WORD:TP}</TP>)?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the filter I used in [Heroku App](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) and reading this [Documentation on how to use grok operators](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE).

I created my own pattern, called "content" that will retrieve whatever it is inside your TP tags.

```
\<ID_APPLICATION\>%{WORD:APPLICATION}\|%{WORD:PROFIL}\|%{WORD:ENV}\|%{WORD:CODE}\<\/ID_APPLICATION\>\<TN>%{NUMBER:TN}\<\/TN\>(\<TP\>(?<content>(.)*)\<\/TP\>)?
```

Basically, I just added an optionnal tag to your pattern.

```
(<TP> ... </TP>)?
```

To retrieve the content, which I assume can be anything, I added the following inside the optional tags.

```
(?<content>(.)*)
```